# Как удалить очередь из ExecutorService но дождаться выполнения выполняющихся потоков?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Есть:

```
 ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadPoolSize);
```

Нужно корректно остановить executor, чтобы не обрывать выполняемые потоки и удалить все ожидающие в очереди.

`shutdownNow()` - валит выполняемые, так нельзя.
`shutdown()` - ждет пока вся очередь вместе с ожидаемыми не закончится, а там их десятки тыс.

Пробовал:

```
BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(threadPoolSize);
executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(threadPoolSize, threadPoolSize, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, queue);
```

затем:

```
executor.shutdown();
 queue.clear();
```

Но что-то здесь не так, поскольку очередь не сбрасывается.

Comment: может сначала стоит сделать queue.clear(); а потом уже shutdown?

Comment: Пробовал, поведение не меняет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот рабочий пример очищения очереди.

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1000);
        ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
                1,
                1,
                0L,
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                queue);

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            int j = i;
            executor.submit(() ->{
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("i = " + j);
            });
        }

        executor.shutdown();
        queue.clear();
    }
}
```

Отрабатывает только одно задание.